# Argument 'Expression' cannot be converted to type 'DataGridViewRow'

Tags: vb.net, argumentexception

I'm getting this error: `Argument 'Expression' cannot be converted to type 'DataGridViewRow'.` I have no clue what it means or how to fix it, it happens at this line:

`dt2.Rows(Val(selectedItem))("Position") = dt.Rows(selectedItem.Cells(1).Value)("Mouse Position")`

Can someone please explain what the error is and how to fix it?

```
    Try

        If selectedItems Is Nothing Then
            For n = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
                dt2.Rows.Add(n)
                dt2.Rows(n)("Position") = dt.Rows.Item(n)("Mouse Position")
            Next

        Else

            For Each selectedItem As DataGridViewRow In selectedItems


                dt2.Rows.Add(selectedItem)
                dt2.Rows(Val(selectedItem))("Position") = dt.Rows(selectedItem.Cells(1).Value)("Mouse Position")

            Next
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error!")
    End Try
```

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: Did you mean to call `.Value` on the end of ("Mouse Position")?

Comment: selectedItem is a DataGridViewRow, right? What is supposed to return the expression Val(DataGridViewRow) ?

Comment: I thought it was just setting the row and column of that datatable = to the selected row of column 2 in the other datatable @Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had to look at your previous question to understand your question.
The variable dt2 is a DataTable with only one column called "Position", so adding a DataGridViewRow to the DataRow collection of this DataTable makes no sense.

Your first loop should be

```
For n = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim r = dt2.NewRow();
    r("Position") = dt.Rows.Item(n)("Mouse Position")
    dt2.Rows.Add(r)
Next
```

while the second loop

```
For Each selectedItem As DataGridViewRow In selectedItems
    Dim r = dt2.NewRow()
    r("Position") = dt.Rows(selectedItem.Cells(1).Value.ToString)("Mouse Position")
    dt2.Rows.Add(r)
Next
```

Comment: Now it says that `Conversion from string to integer is not valid.`

Comment: In the second loop you get the Value of the cell(1) and this is probably a string that need to be converted to an Integer. Check if the update works now.

Comment: With that update it says `Input string is not in correct format`

Comment: Can you tell me what is the content of the Cells(1) of the selectedItem? Is a valid number? In the previous question you used to extract the value from the dt Datatable using `selectedItem.Index`, why now you are using the content of Cells(1)?

Comment: Its `Cursor Position { x coord, y coord}`

Comment: Then remove the conversion to Int32 and use the ToString() at the end of Cells(1).Value.ToString() _Of course the destination row("Position") should be a string_